# T-SQL question about manipulation on strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created stored procedure which returns for example

```
  00001 FROM 40900100001
  00002 from 40900100002
  19999 from 40900119999
```

I want to increase this value to

```
  00001 --> 0002
  00002 --> 00003
  19999 --> 20000
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
DECLARE @Val VARCHAR(20)

SELECT @Val = '00011'

SELECT  REPLICATE('0', LEN(@Val) - LEN(@Val + 1)) + CAST((@Val + 1) AS VARCHAR(20))
```